# Fast convolution algorithm

Tags: delphi, filter, signal-processing, convolution

I need to convolve two one dimensional signals, one has on average 500 points (This one is a Hanning window function), the other 125000. Per run, I need to apply three times the convolution operation. I already have an implementation running based on the documentation of scipy. You can see the code here if you want to (Delphi code ahead):

```
function Convolve(const signal_1, signal_2 : ExtArray) : ExtArray;
var
  capital_k : Integer;
  capital_m : Integer;
  smallest : Integer;
  y : ExtArray;
  n : Integer;
  k : Integer;
  lower, upper : Integer;
begin
  capital_k := Length(signal_1) + Length(signal_2) - 1;
  capital_m := Math.Max(Length(signal_1), Length(signal_2));
  smallest := Math.Min(Length(signal_1), Length(signal_2));
  SetLength(y, capital_k);
  for n := 0 to Length(y) - 1 do begin
    y[n] := 0;
    lower := Math.Max(n - capital_m, 0);
    upper := Math.Min(n, capital_k);
    for k := lower to upper do begin
      if (k >= Length(signal_1)) or (n - k >= Length(signal_2)) then
        Continue;
      y[n] := y[n] + signal_1[k] * signal_2[n - k];
    end;
  end;
  Result := Slice(y,
                  Floor(smallest / 2) - 1,
                  Floor(smallest / 2) - 1 + capital_m);
end;
```

The problem is, this implementation is too slow. The whole procedure takes about five minutes. I was wondering if I can find a faster way of computing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fast convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms) can be carried out using FFTs. Take the FFT of both input signals (with appropriate zero padding), multiply in the frequency domain, then do an inverse FFT. For large N (typically N > 100) this is faster than the direct method.

Comment: What is the zero padding that one needs? It it do make the signals a power of two?

Comment: @Sambatyon: you need zero padding to make the kernel size the same size as the signal (unless you use overlap-add or overlap-save methods) and also you need it to convert circular convolution to linear convolution.

Comment: +1, FFT-multiply-IFFT is definitely the way to go.  In your case, pad both signals to (at least) 125500 points to avoid circular wrapping effects.  Depending on which FFT implementation you use/find, you may need to pad to a power of 2 for speed.

Comment: At least 126500 for applying a length 500 convolution kernel 3 times.  128*1024 might be a good power of 2 length.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of fast convolution algorithms out there. Most of them use FFT routines such as [FFTW](http://fftw.org/). This is because an operation like convolution (in the time domain) reduces to multiplication (of the frequency domain representations) in the frequency domain. A convolution operation that currently takes about 5 minutes (by your own estimates) may take as little as a few seconds once you implement convolution with FFT routines.

Also, if there is a big difference between the length of your filter and the length of your signal, you may also want to consider using Overlap-Save or Overlap-Add. More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap-add_method). If coding in Delphi is not an overriding concern, you might want to use C/C++ if only for the reason that FFTW and some other libraries are available in C/C++ (not sure about scipy or Delphi).