# calculate res[i+j] = a[i]*b[j] in Nlg(N)

Tags: algorithm, fft, convolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fast convolution algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042833/fast-convolution-algorithm)

I have two arrays a and b of N length. I want to calculate the result array as

```
res[i+j] += a[i]*b[j]
```

Is it possible to calculate this using FFT or something similar in time faster than N^2. I saw this question already [1D Fast Convolution without FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237907/1d-fast-convolution-without-fft) but am not sure how to do that using FFT.

```
EG: A=[1,2,3],B[2,4,6]
res[3] = A[1]*B[2]+A[2]*B[1]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show an example to clarify the question? Suppose there are several pairs of indices (i,j) such that a[i]+b[j] is 10. What is the correct value of res[10]?

Comment: Done as required. Sorry for the mistakes before.

Comment: @HOTPOW2: Do you know way how can I generalize that for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand you want the FFT algorithm. [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9388/How-to-implement-the-FFT-algorithm) you have an implementation of this algorithm, and also a good explanation on how to implement the FFT algorithm.

Comment: Any chance you can tell me how I can use it in my case? Thanks

Comment: I would love to give you a 100% sure correct answer. But my guess it that you use  public double[] multiply(double[] p1, double[] p2)  of this link http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/faculty/smithj/oldclass/155f07/solutions/a4/FFT.java. you had to do something like res multiply(a,b); But you have to read and try to understand to be sure.